# White space in drop down list when data is removed

Tags: javascript

image of the issue

[image: 1]

When I try to remove the specified data from this dropdownlist I am still left with a selectable white space where the item use to be, this is the case even if I try to specify by id, I attached an image to demonstrate the issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```js
{
    contentElement.append(
        $("<p>All boardrooms are available at this time.</p><br/>"),

        $("<div style='margin-top:10%' />").attr("id", "selector").dxSelectBox({
            placeholder: "Choose the boardroom you would like to book",
                    //
                    valueExpr: "id",
                    displayExpr: function(item) {                        
                        if(item && item.name != "Training Room" && item.name != "Ada Lovelace" && item.name != "Alexander G Bell")
                            return item.name + " " + '('+item.seats+ " "+'seats'+')';
                    },
                    onOpened: function(e){                                           

                    e.component.option("dataSource", availBoardrooms)
                    e.component.getDataSource().reload();

                },      
                    onValueChanged: function(e){

                    $("[name='boardroom']").val(e.value);
                    $("[name='boardroom']").change();
                    window.name = quickSelectDate;
                }
        })
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are getting invalid data from your data source, you can add a slight validation where you are adding the dropdown options

```
onValueChanged: function(e){
  if(e.value.length) 
  {
      // Add dropdown option 
  }
}
```

Comment: the issue is I am trying to exclude data from my datasource, initially there were 9 items, I removed 3 but am still left with a selectable white space where the item used to be

Comment: Whatever the logic is, But I think when you are adding values there, the value is invalid. So its better before adding values, just check if the string is null or empty.